# is there any function for translating data in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert the data in one of my columns to another language ... is there any function in sql for translating it?

Comment: One way is to use [Google Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs?csw=1) which can dynamically translate text between language pairs. But is a paid service.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I am from Iran and unfortunately I can't use that service... thanks any way

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do it using any inbuilt database feature. You need to do it outside the database.

Comment: I get alot help with this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no SQL functions/procedures for translating between languages built into the Oracle database.

Oracle Text has features for [multi-language indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/amultlng.htm); but that is for indexing documents and not for translating them.

Oracle 12c and later also has features for [translating between different SQL dialects](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAS/translation_examples.htm#DRDAS197); but that is not for translating data.

If you want to translate data then you will need 3rd party solution that you can import into the database or external software that you can call from the database.