# show text in Arabic in RTF template

Tags: arabic, rtf, oracle-bi

I have RTF Template and I need to show words of total amount in Arabic

for example :

Total Amount : 136,369.58

English Format : ONE HUNDRED THIRTY-SIX THOUSAND THREE HUNDRED SIXTY-NINE AND FIFTY-EIGHT

Arabic Format :  مائة وستة وثلاثون ألفًا وثلاثمائة وتسعة وستون ريال وثمانية وخمسون هلله

I used xdoxslt:toCheckNumber($_XDOLOCALE, sum(COLUMN_NAME), ‘EUR’, ‘CASE_UPPER’, ‘DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS’) to get English Format  and it worked fine for English but does not work for Arabic.

I tried many google links to get Arabic Format but I got nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61909889/1509264

Comment: Or of the OP's earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68563296 (setting the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to arabic).

Comment: Thanks for your help , but my requirement is translating with RTF template

Comment: I've removed the oracle database tags since you appear to not want a database solution; if this is incorrect then please re-add the tags (however, then it will probably get closed as a duplicate of one of the questions I've linked previously as they are database solutions).

Answer (score 0):

This working fine , I guess. Good Luck
Remove the space between the first  < and ?

< ?xdoxslt:toCheckNumber('AR-SAR', FINAL_AMOUNT, 2)?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).